# EqualsIgnoreCase() not working as intended.

Tags: java, string, locale, case-sensitive

When i run the following program it prints only

```
equals says they are equal
```

However From  equalsIgnoreCase docs in java 8 we have :

> Two characters c1 and c2 are considered the same ignoring case if at
>   least one of the following is true:
>   • Applying the method
>   java.lang.Character.toUpperCase(char) to each character produces the same result

```
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String string1 = "abc\u00DF";
        String string2 = string1.toUpperCase();

        if (string1.equalsIgnoreCase(string2))
            System.out.println("equalsIgnoreCase says they are equal");

        if (string1.toUpperCase().equals(string2.toUpperCase()))
            System.out.println("equals says they are equal");

    }
}
```

So my question is why this program is not printing

```
equalsIgnoreCase says they are equal
```

As in both operations upper case charcters are used.

Comment: string 1: abcß
string 2: ABCSS, always print intermediary steps or use debugger to see values

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using/comparing the german **ß** sign, its uppercase produce ***SS***... so you need to use the `Locale.German`

```
if (string1.toUpperCase(Locale.GERMAN).equals(string2.toUpperCase(Locale.GERMAN)))
```

that will return true....

Comment: To be more precise: "ß".toUpperCase() == "SS", while Character.toUpperCase('ß') == 'ß'

Comment: Workaround: Don't use equalsIgnoreCase if you have locale-dependant Strings and can't be sure which Locale it is...

Comment: FunFact: In Germany, the lower case sharp s "ß" becomes "SZ" if written in upper case.

Comment: Those silently local aware methods are a terrible Java nightmare, I hate the default values in these.

Comment: Just imagine the pain in the neck for languages like Turkish where they have vowels like: ***I, İ, ı, i***

Comment: @Korashen: that's wrong. since 2006, the replacement for ß in uppercase is only SS. Before that it was possible to use bot SS and SZ

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Really? Well, it's a while since I went to school and they do like to change spelling every now and then... Yet you can still find the usage of SZ today. Guess there are more people who stick to the old(er) versions.

Comment: @Korashen update: from now on, there is a special uppercase for 'ß' (http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_PM_2017-06-29_Aktualisierung_Regelwerk.pdf). I wonder, how to produce that on a normal german keyboard, where shift-ß is mapped to `?`.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch that depends on your OS. On Linux it's `alt gr` + `shift` + `s`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its correct.

> > if (string1.equalsIgnoreCase(string2)) ....

ignores the lower and uppercase of string1 and string2.

> > if (string1.equals(string2)) ....

will detect, that there are different letters and does not print ..they are equal.
Your second example with the uppercase conversion is OK too.

Comment: The question here is why `equalsIgnoreCase` says they are *not* equal.